# How To Zoom image On Mouse Move, the Zoom = Mouse Position, the zoom should be on The Same Image not in another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am required to do this in JavaScript, and it is as follows:
When the cursor moves on the image, the image makes a zoom in the same area in which the cursor stands, and the zoom is on the same image in the same element and not in another element
Please help me, I am confused and cannot use (Offset and Pagex)

Comment: How to ask question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

HTML:

```
<div id="imgContainer" style="background-size:200%">
    <img src="imge.png" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
let imgContainer = document.getElementById('imgContainer');

imgContainer.style.backgroundImage = "url('imge.png')";

imgContainer.addEventListener('mouserover' function(event){
  let zoomer = event.currentTarget;
  let offsetX = 0;
  let offsetY = 0;
  offsetX = (event.offsetX) ? event.offsetX : event.touches[0].pageX;
  offsetY = (event.offsetY) ? event.offsetY : event.touches[0].pageY;
  let x = offsetX / zoomer.offsetWidth*100;
  let y = offsetY / zoomer.offsetHeight*100;
  imgContainer.style.backgroundPosition = `${x}% ${y}%`;
})
```

CSS:

```
.imgContainer:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
}
```